# Titanium ImageView animation width and height

Tags: ios, animation, imageview, titanium

I try to create an ImageView in Titanium like this:

```
var animationView = Titanium.UI.createImageView
(
    {
        images:animationImages,
        duration:50,
        repeatCount:0,
        width: '90dp',
        height: '270dp'
    }
);
```

On android it gets its size as expected, but on IOS, it simply doesn't gets scaled. Is there something, i'm doing wrong? Or should i do it frame by frame by creating the ImageViews manually then changing them with `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to create my own animation class, which look like this:

```
function Animation(data)
{
    var width = data.hasOwnProperty("width") ? data.width : Ti.UI.SIZE;
    var height = data.hasOwnProperty("height") ? data.height: Ti.UI.SIZE;
    var duration = data.hasOwnProperty("duration") ? data.duration : 50;
    var imageFiles = data.hasOwnProperty("images") ? data.images : [];

    var images = [];

    var container = Ti.UI.createView
    (
        {
            width:width,
            height: height
        }
    );

    for(var i=0; i<imageFiles.length; i++)
    {
        var image = Ti.UI.createImageView
        (
            {
                image:imageFiles[i],
                width:width,
                height:height
            }
        );

        if(i!=0)
            image.setVisible(false);

        container.add(image);
        images.push(image);
    }

    container.activeImage = 0;
    container.intervalId = null;

    container.setActiveImage = function(index)
    {
        if(container.intervalId == null)
            container.activeImage = index;
    }

    container.start = function()
    {
        var callback = function()
        {
            for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++)
            {
                if(i == container.activeImage)
                    images[i].setVisible(true);
                else
                    images[i].setVisible(false);
            }

            container.activeImage = (container.activeImage + 1) % images.length;
        }

        container.intervalId = setInterval ( callback, duration );
    }

    container.stop = function()
    {
        clearInterval(container.intervalId);
        container.intervalId = null;
    }

    return container;
}

module.exports = Animation;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var Animation = require('...path to your animation file');
var myAnimation = new Animation
(
    {
        width:'100dp',
        height:'100dp',
        duration:50, //duration while one frame is showing
        images:['one.png', 'two.png'...], //full paths
    }
);

//start:
myAnimation.start();

//stop
myAnimation.stop();
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much. I haven't tried it yet, but have you had any performance issues? I was thinking of using views instead of imageviews, the other idea that I had was to just use one image and change the backgroundImage property. One more thing. It seems that your code repeats the animation till it's cancelled. I was also thinking of adding a parameter for looping. Anyways I will try all these outs in the next few days and post results. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Leonardo I think, it's not the most performance-friendly thing to do, but it gets the job done :) When i have the time, i will look into it again, and add looping. I'm glad, you liked it!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not a consistent solution, it should be a comment, but since I don't have enough rep I have to write it as an answer.

For starters I would try to give it a top and left properties.
Secondly, are those images retrieved from a remote URL? Remote URLs are only supported in Android. If that is the case you could do a workaround as you said in the question.

Finally, the 'dp' only works for android, so it won't scale at all in iOS, it will simply erase the 'dp' and use the number as "points", on non-retina screens it will be the same number of pixels and on a retina display it will be the double.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i finally decided to create the animation frame by frame, setting only one image visible at a time.